# How to parse json data in WPF C#?

Tags: c#

I want to parse json data.  Below is my json response.

```
{
    "error": true,
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "Enter a valid email address."
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is my sample code.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(res);

string Status = (string)obj["error"];

if (Status == "True" || Status == "true")   
{
    string email = obj["errors"]["email"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(email );
    return;
}
```

but I am getting email value is `'["Enter a valid email address."]'`.

I want to remove `'[]'`. How to do this?

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=cE3y0zuFt2tCDV6fbgxi Almost every JSON parsing problem is solved 10x quicker if you serialise to a concrete type first.

Comment: `email` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email` in the sample json given in OP, is an array. If you need to access all values in the array, you need to loop through each element in the array. For example

```
foreach(var emailValue in obj["errors"]["email"])
{
string email = (string)emailValue;
// do rest
}
```

If you only need the first element in the array, you could use

```
var email = (string)obj["errors"]["email"][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless your schema is dynamic you're almost always better off going with a type-safe approach i.e.:

```
public class Errors
{
    public string[] email { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserializing like this:

```
var json = "{\"error\": true, \"errors\": { \"email\": [\"Enter a valid email address.\"]}}";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
```